# Getting 'Multiple Primary Keys' error in Laravel. How to create an autoincrement, unique column without making it primary?

Tags: laravel

I have this migration in Laravel which I bumped into, I am getting an error:

> Multiple primary keys

I want the `biometric_id` to be auto increment and unique at the same time without it being the primary key.

```php
Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('employee_id', 150)->primary();
    $table->integer('biometric_id', true)->unique();
    $table->string('employee_fname', 150)->nullable();
    $table->string('employee_mname', 150)->nullable();
    $table->string('employee_lname', 150)->nullable();
    $table->string('employee_ext', 150)->nullable();
    //other tables...
    
});
```

I tried doing this, but it didn't work.

```php
Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('employee_id', 150)->unique();
    $table->integer('biometric_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('employee_fname', 150)->nullable();
    $table->string('employee_mname', 150)->nullable();
    $table->string('employee_lname', 150)->nullable();
    $table->string('employee_ext', 150)->nullable();
    //other tables...
    
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE employees MODIFY biometric_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT');
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that one is the one giving you errors? Instead of `integer` try [`foreignId`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#column-method-foreignId) or [`foreingIdFor`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#column-method-foreignIdFor)

Comment: What is  the primary key in these `biometric_id` or `employee_id`?

Comment: Which of the two approaches produces that error? I wouldn't expect the 1st one to do that. At any rate move the `DB::statement` outside the `Schema::create` callback because at that point the table has not been created yet

Comment: @AbdullaNilam employee_id should be the primary, I also tried the composite keys and no avail

Comment: @apokryfos tried doing this

i get: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key (SQL: ALTER TABLE employees MODIFY biometric_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT)

Comment: If you are passing `autoincrement` to biometric id, then laravel automatically sets it to primary key, that is your issue. I remember helping someone a long time ago with the same issue, but I do not remember how that user solved it

Comment: @matiaslauriti what i did was i made a new migration like this, will this work? i dont have an idea, but when i run the migration it worked. How can i check if the column is modified already?

 public function up()
    {
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE employees MODIFY biometric_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT');
    }

Comment: What you are trying to do makes no sense at all, why are you adding `biometic_id` and have it autoincrement? You already have `employee_id` (it should be `id`, normalize your database). So both columns are going to have the same number every time, you are duplicating data, that is very bad

Comment: I already fixed and and decided to use employee_id instead as only primary. Thank you for the inputs and suggestions.